# Warning using microtype and exCJK packages

Tags: microtype, xecjk

Compiling the following MWE

```
\documentclass[twoside,10pt,a4paper]{report}%,twocolumn

\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{fontspec} % 
\usepackage{xeCJK}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

I get one of these amusing warnings:

> Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
>   (microtype) `\'A' (microtype) in font encoding`EU1' in inheritance
>   list

My questions are: What does it means ? And should I care ?

Comment: Quick fix: load `microtype` after `fontspec`.